# How to use button in repeater control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I am using asp.net 3.5 with c#.I want to invoke button click event inside repeater control.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptFriendsList"
    runat="server" 
    onitemcommand="rptFriendsList_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnSave"
                         runat="server" 
                         ImageUrl="~/Contents/Images/save_button.png"
                         CommandName="Schedule"
                         UseSubmitBehavior="False"  />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

but when i click to a button its giving an error

> "Invalid postback or callback
>   argument.  Event validation is enabled
>   using  in
>   configuration or <%@ Page
>   EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a
>   page.  For security purposes, this
>   feature verifies that arguments to
>   postback or callback events originate
>   from the server control that
>   originally rendered them.  If the data
>   is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation
>   method in order to register the
>   postback or callback data for
>   validation."

my purpose is to execute some code in button click which is placed inside the repeater.Please  help me to solve this issue.Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you adding items to the repeater's data source (and when)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UseSubmitBehavior="False"**  this property you have used is not present with the image button have you over ridden imagebutton class and added this property.

Answer (score 5):

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server"      OnItemCommand="Repeater1_OnItemCommand"  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">


            <ItemTemplate>
                key1:
                <asp:Label ID="key1Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("key1") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                key2:
                <asp:Label ID="key2Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("key2") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                key3:
                <asp:Label ID="key3Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("key3") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="col1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("col1") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:TextBox ID="col2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("col2") %>'></asp:TextBox>


                <br />


                <asp:linkbutton ID="Linkbutton1" commandname="Update" runat="server" text="Update"  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("key1") +"|"+Eval("key2")+"|"+ Eval("key3") %>' />
               <asp:linkbutton ID="Linkbutton2" commandname="Cancel" runat="server" text="Cancel" />


            </ItemTemplate>



 protected void Repeater1_OnItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Update")
        {

            string col1 = ((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("col1")).Text;
            string col2 = ((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("col2")).Text;


            string allKeys = Convert.ToString(e.CommandArgument);

            string[] arrKeys = new string[2];
            char[] splitter = { '|' };
            arrKeys = allKeys.Split(splitter);



            SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["col1"].DefaultValue = col1;
            SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["col2"].DefaultValue = col2;

            SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["key1"].DefaultValue = arrKeys[0];
            SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["key2"].DefaultValue = arrKeys[1];
            SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["key3"].DefaultValue = arrKeys[2];


            SqlDataSource1.Update();          

            Repeater1.DataBind();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This also happens when you have assigned the datasource and data bound your repeater in the OnLoad event rather than OnInit

Answer (score 1):

I have used this bellow code and runs ok
use this bellow code in .aspx page

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Edit
                </th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="Edit">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Use this in .cs Make the event Repeater1_ItemCommand

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{

    switch (e.CommandName)
    {
        case "Edit":
            // Do some stuff when the Edit button is clicked.

            break;

        // Other commands here.

        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use button, because button create postback on click and also itemcommand of repeater called!

But, If you want to use asp:button instead of asp:linkbutton, you have to set UseSubmitBehavior property of button to false. its means, button dont make postback.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAccept" runat="server" Text="Accept All" CssClass="vb-default vb-green vb-txt-light" CommandName="Accept" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UserID") %>' UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Set page EnableEventValidation="false".

Comment: This is a last resort option - the EventValidation prevents all kind of evil from being submitted to your site.

Answer (score -2):

if you're adding items server side, try to assign unique ID to each ImageButton

Comment: If they're in a repeater, they get a uniqueid by default, in this case something like: rptFriendsList_ItemCommand_btnSave)

Comment: what if the ClientIDMode is set to Static?

Comment: Then it's a different question