# Asp.net web form passing argument on button click generated inside loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am generating buttons inside **foreach** loop

```
<% foreach (var myObject in myObjectList)
   {
%>
       <b>Text field</b>: <%= myObject.Text%><br>                     
       <asp:Button ID="" runat="server" OnClick="WaitQueueDeleteBtn_Click" CommandArgument="pass myObjectText" Text="Delete"/>

<% } %>
```

It seems that I cannot use `myObject`'s field inside `CommandArgument` however `myObjectList` is accessible

i.e

```
<asp:Button ID="" runat="server" OnClick="WaitQueueDeleteBtn_Click" CommandArgument="<%#myObjectList.Count%>" Text="Delete"/>
```

The above statement would work but the one below would not

```
<asp:Button ID="" runat="server" OnClick="WaitQueueDeleteBtn_Click" CommandArgument="<%#myObject.Text %>" Text="Delete"/>
```

Any idea why? And how can I pass `myObject`'s field values as `CommandArgument`?

**Update**:

Button method in class

```
protected void WaitQueueDeleteBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: how the method `WaitQueueDeleteBtn_Click` is defined

Comment: @un-lucky I have updated the question

Comment: what is `myObject`? will it have a property called `Text`? `.Count` is working means it may be abollection. could you please recheck

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aspx Web Forms Command argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244072/aspx-web-forms-command-argument)

Comment: yes myObject has property called Text myObjectList is List of some class let's say Foo. So myObjectList is List<Foo> and myObject is Foo and Foo has property Text

Comment: @SehaxX So basically it's not possible using foreach?

Comment: Seems so, I always use repeaters as this is the way to go with webforms. The code is almost similar what you already have. See this for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309991/how-to-use-button-in-repeater-control

Comment: Why you didn't use Repeater?

Answer (score 1):

It's so easy with [Repeater](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Markup**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div><b>Text field</b>: <%# Eval("Text") %></div>
        <asp:Button runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' Text="Delete" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**C#**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Repeater1.DataSource = YOUR_DATA_SOURCE; // myObjectList
        Repeater1.DataBind();

        // ...
    }
}

protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandArgument == null) return;

    var id = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());

    // your logic here ...
}
```

You can add multiple buttons and using `CommandName` can figure out which one clicked.

Hope this helps.